# Is it permissible for a female to work?

Tags: women, fiqh, work

UAE is encouraging their girls to study and job.  Despite [Modi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narendra_Modi) (Prime Minister of India) saying our minority Muslim females don't study or do jobs, I think Islam gives female right to decide whether she wants to go out for work and study or not. If she wants than she can go by wearing scarf or right attire like burkha.

Is it permissible for a female to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah has mentioned in the Quran several times that He views men and women equally. The following link quotes the Quran and describes reasons why females are oppressed in some cultures (mainly to do with beliefs from texts **other** than the word of Allah).

[Equality of Men and Women](http://www.submission.info/perspectives/women/equality.html).

Therefore to give an answer: **yes, women are allowed to work if you consider them equal to men.**

Comment: How does it sort with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An-Nisa,_34 ?

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly it ought to be mentioned that your inquiry can be considered
  as practical and significant question especially for nowadays. Since
  the situation of the societies has changed …
- Secondly as a general rule, it would be permissible for women working
  in normal conditions. (By observing Islamic doctrines, such as
  Islamic veil code, stop having unnecessary talking or even laughing
  to non-mahrams and so forth).
- Thirdly there could be some jobs as the    necessary jobs which need
  to the attendance of the women, such as:    Doctor, nurse, nursery
  teacher, and so on. (I mean the works which    really are needed to
  women, not using excuse to choose every    unnecessary jobs.) / At
  least they endear to choose the works which    have the lowest amount
  of visiting non-mahrams…
- Fourthly, on the whole, psychologist believe that attending on work
  for women could be led to lack of sufficient children training,
  therefore it will be a problem for the future of our children…
- Fifthly, I named it as a permissible practice, but at many of times
  there could be the fields of the different sins for them such as
  “looking or staring to the girls by boys” which would leads some
  sins… or even talking between non-mahrams which could be the start of
  …. Note: What I said, doesn’t mean that women must definitely stay
  home and …, no, I didn’t mean working is haram for them, but I named
  some ways which can be counted as the ways of sin by their attendance
  on work.
- Sixthly, many psychologist believe that working for women could be as
  a reason for the delay in getting married. How come? Since they’ll
  get the opportunity of getting a job for a man, then he’ll delay his
  marriage till find a job. Consequently I myself would not to go on
  work in order to help others getting marriage (if I was a woman) /
  then I’m strongly believe that Allah will give us a great bless (in
  our life) if the women ignore going on work due to the mentioned
  items (to make Allah more satisfied …)

**Conclusion:**

It doesn’t seem as a haram deed for women to work (as a general rule), thus don’t look at this matter as an impermissible or forbidden act. Even Shia counts it as a halal or permissible act for woman to work (According to Shia's hadiths from Shia Imams), but by observing ...) / But on the other hand, there could be many important items which indeed are more valuable for women if they endeavor to stay home as much as possible (not by force, actually by paying attention to some items as I named some of them above).  Consequently, definitely Allah will give them an extensive reward in this world and likewise doomsday if they avoid going on work by the intention of the above-mentioned items and so forth. But you are the final and main persons who decide about your futures. Good luck all of you.

---

**Reference:**

[www.wikifeqh.ir](https://web.archive.org/web/20171123004631/http://www.wikifeqh.ir:80/%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%BA%D8%A7%D9%84_%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86)

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible for a female to work along with proper hijab and conditions according to Islam. For women as per Islam it's better to be in home unless there's a need for her to earn.

Regarding Modi let women be secondary firstly he have to check how the men of minority is doing in his country. I am not saying it's worse but there is a lot of matters to be taken seriously of minority.
those who are rich will not feel anything much or even close, to see the situation we have to view from the eye of a poor.